# SLO with WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I use APIManager 2.6.0 and IS 5.7.0. I configured SSO for api store and publisher using OAuth2.0 using this doc https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+Single+Sign-on+with+OpenID+Connect.

I have a problem with SLO. When I log out in api publisher and then switch to api store then I'm logged out in api publisher but i'm still logged in api store.

Is it possible to configure SLO in the way that when I log out in one of the products then I'm logged out in all pages?

Answer (score 1):

In OIDC there are three mechanisms to handle logout. OIDC Session management, OIDC back channel logout, OIDC front channel logout are them, out of these three WSO2 Identity Server supports OIDC session management [1]. But still the limitation is  api store and publisher has not been written in a way to support OIDC Session management. Due to above reason its not possible to achieve your requirement.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Session+Management+with+Playground